# Output a list of properties for a data attribute in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a form with various inputs allowing the user to built the properties of a component, see the code for the component and render a preview of the component, while updating the form.
The issue I have is trying to output the results of a checkbox to build the properties of an attribute.

This is the HTML for the element that is used to both preview and provide the code snippet:

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-default " data-placement="top" role="button" data-toggle="popover"
   data-trigger=""
   title="Edit Tooltip text above"
   data-content="Edit popover content above">
   Popover Button Text
</a>
```

The following code is the Angular driven template pre-compiled

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn {{btnClass.cssClass || 'btn-default'}} {{btnSize.cssClass || ''}}" data-placement="{{toolTipPosition.cssClass || ''}}" role="button" data-toggle="popover"
   data-trigger="{{item.enabled ? item.triggerEv+' ' : ''}}"
   title="{{popoverTitle || 'Edit Tooltip text above'}}"
   data-content="{{popoverContent || 'Edit popover content above'}}">
   {{popoverBtnText || 'Popover Button Text'}}
</a>
```

As you can see from the first example (the compiled code) all of the properties are rendering as expected until you get to `data-trigger`

The data for the data attribute is built via a checkbox list:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in popoverTriggers">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.triggerEv" >
    <span>&nbsp;{{item.name}} </span>
</div>
```

and the AngularJS model is as follows:

```
$scope.popoverTriggers = [{
    name: "Hover",
    triggerEv: "hover",
    enabled: false
},{
    name: "Toggle",
    triggerEv: "click",
    enabled: false
}, {
    name: "Focus (Dismissible)",
    triggerEv: "focus",
    enabled: false
}, {
    name: "Manual",
    triggerEv: "manual",
    enabled: false
}];
```

If the user were to select "Hover" and "Focus (Dismissible)" for example, the expected output would be

```
data-trigger="focus hover"
```

I'm not sure if my model is incorrect, but I think that even if I change my the structure of the `popoverTriggers` model, I would still need to know how to render each of the selected properties as a space delimited list in a data attribute. I can't use (or cannot see how to use) ng-repeat within an html attribute. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems like this must be either a difficult one to answer or I'm barking up the wrong tree trying to get Angular to do something it isn't meant to do!
I have been thinking that the way forward would be to update a data model (like I am already) and making a directive to handle the change function to update the html attributes. I will post it when I have completed it